# How to solved pdftex.def not found in windows in texlive-2016

Tags: graphics

Please help me when i run latex file it stuck on pdftex.def not found. I am using texlive 2016 , operating system is windows 7 , 32 bit newly installed texlive in our friends office.

Comment: just update texlive and it should be there

Comment: when i run the command in cmd "tlmgr update --all" it says no update, it still stuck at pdftex.def not found it says graphics.sty at line 100 @DavidCarlisle